# php login script if returns else even though login info is correct in db

Tags: php, mysql

This block of code is to login as an admin for the backend of my page I'm building. It parses to the 'else' statement echoing my "Incorrect Information" statement. Basically saying it isn't finding the credentials I created on the server which I have checked and double checked. Also confirmed that my connection script is working. I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
  header("location: index.php");
  exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters 
      $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters 
      // Connect to the MySQL database
      include "../php/connect_to_mysql.php";
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // Query the person
//------MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS-----
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Count the row nums
if ($existCount == 1) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $id = $row["id"];
    }
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
  } else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, <a href="index.php">try again</a>.';
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

This is the form code

```
<form name="adminform" id="adminform" method="post" action="admin_login.php">
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-2 columns">
                  <label class="inline">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="large-10 columns">
                  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="JohnDoe" name="username">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-2 columns">
                  <label class="inline">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="large-10 columns">
                  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Shazam" name="password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="radius button">Log In</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Try to `echo "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"` and see the result, then run the echoed query using phpmyadmin or similar and see if it works.

Comment: Can you try to connect to mysql from your php file instead of just include it? Also try to add the `link_identifier` to `mysql_query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that even if you are checking the $_POST var, when you do the filter you use $_SESSION values. Try with the $_POST one.

```
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);

    // ...
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help!